# Struct memory layout in C

Tags: c, struct, memory-layout

I have a C# background. I am very much a newbie to a low-level language like C.

In C#, `struct`'s memory is laid out by the compiler by default. The compiler can re-order data fields or pad additional bits between fields implicitly. So, I had to specify some special attribute to override this behavior for exact layout.

AFAIK, C does not reorder or align memory layout of a `struct` by default. However, I heard there's a little exception that is very hard to find.

What is C's memory layout behavior? What should be re-ordered/aligned and not?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

In C, the compiler is allowed to dictate some alignment for every primitive type. Typically the alignment is the size of the type. But it's entirely implementation-specific.

Padding bytes are introduced so every object is properly aligned. Reordering is not allowed.

Possibly every remotely modern compiler implements `#pragma pack` which allows control over padding and leaves it to the programmer to comply with the ABI. (It is strictly nonstandard, though.)

From C99 §6.7.2.1:

> 12    Each non-bit-field member of a
> structure or union object is aligned
> in an implementation- defined manner
> appropriate to its type.
>
> 13    Within a
> structure object, the non-bit-field
> members and the units in which
> bit-fields reside have addresses that
> increase in the order in which they
> are declared. A pointer to a structure
> object, suitably converted, points to
> its initial member (or if that member
> is a bit-field, then to the unit in
> which it resides), and vice versa.
> There may be unnamed padding within a
> structure object, but not at its
> beginning.

Comment: Some compilers (i.e. GCC) implement the same effect as `#pragma pack` but with more fine-grained control over the semantics.

Comment: C11 also has `_Alignas`.

Answer (score 150):

It's implementation-specific, but in practice the rule (in the absence of `#pragma pack` or the like) is:

- Struct members are stored in the order they are declared.  (This is required by the C99 standard, as mentioned here earlier.)
- If necessary, padding is added between struct members, to ensure that the latter one uses the correct alignment.
- Each primitive type T requires an alignment of `sizeof(T)` bytes.

So, given the following struct:

```
struct ST
{
   char ch1;
   short s;
   char ch2;
   long long ll;
   int i;
};
```

- `ch1` is at offset 0
- a padding byte is inserted to align...
- `s` at offset 2
- `ch2` is at offset 4, immediately after s
- 3 padding bytes are inserted to align...
- `ll` at offset 8
- `i` is at offset 16, right after ll
- 4 padding bytes are added at the end so that the overall struct is a multiple of 8 bytes.  I checked this on a 64-bit system: 32-bit systems may allow structs to have 4-byte alignment.

So `sizeof(ST)` is 24.

It can be reduced to 16 bytes by rearranging the members to avoid padding:

```
struct ST
{
   long long ll; // @ 0
   int i;        // @ 8
   short s;      // @ 12
   char ch1;     // @ 14
   char ch2;     // @ 15
} ST;
```

Comment: If neccessary, padding is added before ... More like after. Best add a final `char` member to your example.

Comment: A primitive type does not necessarily require an alignment of `sizeof(T)` bytes.  For example, a `double` on common 32-bit architectures is 8 bytes but [often only requires 4-byte alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11110283/706054).  Furthermore, the padding at the end of the struct only pads to the alignment of the widest struct member.  For example, a struct of 3 char variables could have no padding.

Comment: @dan04, would it be a good practice to layout structs in the descending order of sizeof(T). Would there be any downsides to doing this ?

Comment: Isn't there guaranteed to be a zero offset for the first member, meaning there can't be any padding before it?

Answer (score 14):

You can start by reading the [data structure alignment wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) to get a better understanding of data alignment.

From the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment):

> Data alignment means putting the data at a memory offset equal to some multiple of the word size, which increases the system's performance due to the way the CPU handles memory. To align the data, it may be necessary to insert some meaningless bytes between the end of the last data structure and the start of the next, which is data structure padding.

From [6.54.8 Structure-Packing Pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html) of the GCC documentation:

> For compatibility with Microsoft
>   Windows compilers, GCC supports a set
>   of #pragma directives which change the
>   maximum alignment of members of
>   structures (other than zero-width
>   bitfields), unions, and classes
>   subsequently defined. The n value
>   below always is required to be a small
>   power of two and specifies the new
>   alignment in bytes.
>
> 1. `#pragma pack(n)` simply sets the new alignment.
> 2. `#pragma pack()` sets the alignment to the one that was in
>      effect when compilation started (see
>      also command line option
>      -fpack-struct[=] see Code Gen Options).
> 3. `#pragma pack(push[,n])` pushes the current alignment setting on an
>      internal stack and then optionally
>      sets the new alignment.
> 4. `#pragma pack(pop)` restores the alignment setting to the one saved at
>      the top of the internal stack (and
>      removes that stack entry). Note that
>      `#pragma pack([n])` does not influence this internal stack; thus it is
>      possible to have `#pragma pack(push)`
>      followed by multiple `#pragma pack(n)`
>      instances and finalized by a single
>      `#pragma pack(pop)`.
>
> Some targets, e.g. i386 and powerpc,
>   support the ms_struct `#pragma` which
>   lays out a structure as the documented
>   `__attribute__ ((ms_struct))`.
>
> 1. `#pragma ms_struct on` turns on the layout for structures declared.
> 2. `#pragma ms_struct off` turns off the layout for structures declared.
> 3. `#pragma ms_struct reset` goes back to the default layout.

Comment: Thanks for care. I modified question as you guided.