# Order of storage inside a structure / object

Tags: c++, c, class, pointers, structure

Consider these two cases :

```
struct customType
{
   dataType1 var1; 
   dataType2 var2;
   dataType3 var3;
} ;

customType instance1;
// Assume var1, var2 and var3 were initialized to some valid values.

customType * instance2 = &instance1;    
dataType1 firstMemberInsideStruct = (dataType1)(*instance2);
```

---

```
class CustomType
{
   public:
       dataType1 member1;
       dataType2 member2;

       retrunType1 memberFunction1();

   private:
       dataType3 member3;
       dataType4 member4;

       retrunType2 memberFunction2();
};

customType object;
// Assume member1, member2, member3 and member4 were initialized to some valid values.

customType *pointerToAnObject = &object ;
dataType1 firstMemberInTheObject = (dataType1) (*pointerToAnObject);
```

Is it *always* safe to do this ?

I want to know if standard specifies any order of storage among -

1. The elements inside a C structure.
2. Data members inside an object of a C++ class.

Comment: Definitely not if the class is polymorphic. But I'm not sure on the technical details of when exactly it's safe to do.

Comment: in c++ classes and structs are basically the same besides the keyword. The Dataorder is as you descrtibed, but if you want to be 100% sure you can use inheritance, if you just need to access the first object. Btw why don't you create direct pointers to the members then you can do something like `*(classInstancepointer->memberpointer)` (approximately has been a while) to access the data, by exchanging the instance pointer you can access the data in different Instances.

Comment: I don't think it is a generally safe thing to do in C++: you have to take base (derived from) classes into consideration. The order of the member variables, is guaranteed to match the source. It is not very different for C and C++: C++ classes can have parent classes and a table of virtual methods, which C does not have. This makes the result of "firstMemberInObject" somewhat harder to read from the source. Besides, alignment of the fields can add come padding before the first field.

Comment: @ted: &instance.member, which is completely safe thing to do

Comment: @fork0 `&instance.member` is to set up the pointer, yezx i forgot to put that. But I think I can racall something like `auto p=&class::member` and `auto inst=&class()` to be used ass member and instance pointer in the code I mentioned above. In your case it looks like you are already getting a bound object pointer which i think difers slightly from the desired result.

Comment: @ted: this `&class::member` works only for static elements of a class. That'd be static variables and methods (you can get an address of a method by `&` operator). The other construction is actually an error: you get an address to a temporary object. Still can have its uses though: as an argument to a function: `func(&class())`. Using a reference in this argument will make it shorter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C99 and C++ differ a bit on this.

The C99 standard guarantees that the fields of a struct will be laid out in memory in the order they are declared, and that the fields of two identical structs will have the same offsets.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748995/c-struct-memory-layout) for the relevant sections of the C99 standard.  To summarize: the offset of the first field is specified to be zero, but the offsets after that are not specified by the standard.  This is to allow C compilers to adjust the offsets of each field so the field will satisfy any memory alignment requirements of the architecture.  Because this is implementation-dependent, C provides a standard way to determine the offset of each field using the [`offsetof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) macro.

C++ offers this guarantee only for [Plain old data (POD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure).  C++ classes that are not plain old data cannot be treated like this.  The standard gives the C++ compiler quite a bit of freedom in how it organizes a class when the class uses multiple inheritance, has non-public fields or members, or contains virtual members.

What this means for your examples:

```
dataType1 firstMemberInsideStruct = (dataType1)(*instance2);
```

This line is okay *only if* dataType1, dataType2, and dataType3 are plain old data.  If any of them are not, then the customType struct may not have a trivial constructor (or destructor) and this assumption may not hold.

```
dataType1 firstMemberInTheObject = (dataType1) (*pointerToAnObject);
```

This line is not safe regardless of whether `dataType1`, `dataType2`, and `dataType3` are POD, because the `CustomType` class has private instance variables.  This makes it *not* a POD class, and so you cannot assume that its first instance variable will be ordered in a particular way.

Answer (score 6):

9.0.7

> A standard-layout class is a class that: — has no non-static data
>   members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or
>   reference, — has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base
>   classes (10.1), — has the same access control (Clause 11) for all
>   non-static data members, — has no non-standard-layout base classes, —
>   either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at
>   most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base
>   classes with non-static data members, and — has no base classes of the
>   same type as the first non-static data member.108

9.2.14

> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access
>   control (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher
>   addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static
>   data members with different access control is unspecified (11).
>   Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members
>   not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might
>   requirements for space for managing virtual functions (10.3) and
>   virtual base classes (10.1).

9.2.20

> A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using
>   a reinterpret_cast, points to its initial member (or if that member is
>   a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa. [
>   Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a
>   standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning, as necessary
>   to achieve appropriate alignment. — end note ]

Answer (score 1):

It's not always safe to do so. If the classes have `virtual` methods, it most definitely is not. Data members are guaranteed to appear in the same order for the same access level chunk, but these groups can be reordered.

**In order to be safe with these type of casts, you should provide a conversion constructor or a cast operator, and not rely on implementation details.**

Answer (score 0):

Typically in a C struct members are stored in the order that they are declared. However the elements must be aligned properly. Wikipedia has a good example of [how this works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86).

I will re-iterate here:

If you have the following struct

```
struct MixedData
{
    char Data1;
    short Data2;
    int Data3;
    char Data4;
};
```

padding will be inserted in between differing data types in order to assure the proper byte-alignment. `char`s are 1-byte aligned, `short`s are 2-byte aligned, `int`s are 4-byte aligned, etc.

Thus to make `Data2` 2-byte aligned, there will be a 1-byte padding inserted between `Data1` and `Data2`.

It is also worth mentioning that there are mechanisms that can change the packing alignment. See [#pragma pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: The first statement is wrong in case of interleaving private-public-protected fields.

Comment: C has no such mechanism. Sorry, perhaps I should have said typically in C. I don't have the authority to say anything about C++ :P