# What happens if I copy a `struct` with an `array[3]` in it?

Tags: c++, arrays, unions

I have this structure which I've been using without bugs so far:

```
union Vector3f
{
  struct{ float x,y,z ; } ;
  float elts[3];
} ;
```

There are a couple of overloaded constructors, but I left the copy constructor and assignment `operator=` to their default implementations.

```
Vector3f a,b ;
b=a; //works as expected, with x,y,z copied over from a to b
```

It just occurred to me that default memberwise assignment should execute `b.elts=a.elts`, which since `elts` is a pointer type, should result in `b.elts` incorrectly pointing to `a.elts`.

However, explicitly attempting `b.elts=a.elts` fails with compilation error

> Array type float[3] is not assignable

Is this something to worry about?  Is my code ok or should I explicitly write a copy ctor and assignment `operator=`?

Comment: In title you mentioned `struct`, but in the body you wrote `union`. Which is your actual question?

Comment: `elts` is not a pointer type.

Comment: Don't use a union this way. It's undefined behavior to read from a union member that hasn't been assigned to directly, so you get little use from this representation. The trick may technically work, but it's always a bit ugly and unstable. Use a regular class with `operator[]` or `x()`, `y()` and `z()`.

Comment: Note that an array of 3 elements is not required to have the same layout as three distinct elements.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, I've heard [this argument before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2313676/111307), it's basically a misconception (see comment thread below answer).

Comment: @bobobobo - please point to the requirement in the standard that `float elts[3]` and `float f; float g; float h;` must have the same layout.

Comment: Those floats are declared inside an anonymous struct.  `struct { float f,g,h; };` will be stored contiguously and in order (assuming the compiler does not insert any padding).  [Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11340165/111307)