# How to get sample rate from wav file?

Tags: c++, audio, wav, oboe

I am using oboe lib for sound playback

https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/docs/FullGuide.md

as a sound file I am using `.wav` file. As far as I know there is a way to get from `.wav` file header - sample rate.

So, question is - how to pro grammatically in C++ read the sample rate from an arbitrary `.wav` file?

Comment: Is the question how to programmatically in C++ read the sample rate from an arbitrary wav file?

Comment: Are you asking how to read a file, where the header is in a WAV file, or how to understand a WAV file header?

Comment: @foolo yes, edited my question

Comment: Start by learning about the structure of the [wav format/header](http://tiny.systems/software/soundProgrammer/WavFormatDocs.pdf). Then write code to read and parse it.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://google.github.io/oboe/reference/classoboe_1_1_audio_stream_base.html#ae9d32f3e09174bad69e74f147ee33087), you can get the sample rate of an `AudioStream` with `getSampleRate()`, but it is maybe not the best way in your case.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard functionality in C++ for parsing wav files.

The bytes at indices 24-27 of the header represent a 32 bit integer that is the sample rate in Hz.

Comment: But, maybe you familiar with `oboe` lib? Is there no way to get `sample rate` using this lib?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko I'm not familiar with the library, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your own WAV parser, perhaps look at this question (note one error in the code which is corrected in my answer): [printing of a wav header in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318685/printing-of-a-wav-header-in-c/17319446#17319446)

But probably it is more convenient to use a library. For instance, [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/api.html) has an API `sf_open` that returns an SF_INFO struct, that includes the sample rate.

Comment: But, maybe you familiar with `oboe` lib? Is there no way to get `sample rate` using this lib?