# Why does mixing types in Python struct.pack uses more space than needed?

Tags: python, pack

I have just tried using struct.pack in Python for the first time, and I don't understand its behaviour when I am mixing types

When I am trying to pack a single char and nothing else, it works as expected, i.e.

```
struct.pack("b",1)
```

gives `'\x01'`. But as soon as I try to mix in data of a different type, the char is padded to be as long as this type, e.g.

```
struct.pack("bi",1,1)
```

gives `'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'`.

Is this standard behaviour, and why? Is there a way around it?

**Edit**

More simply put:

```
>>> struct.calcsize("b")
1
>>> struct.calcsize("i")
4
>>> struct.calcsize("bi")
8
```

Comment: And surprisingly: `struct.calcsize('d')` → 8, `struct.calcsize('bd')` ­­→ 16.  Alignment and padding seems to be depending on the other types.  That's not intuitive, even if you expect alignment. EDIT: Ah, I see, the size of the `'d'` is 8, and that determines where it can start (at multiples of 8), hence the padding.

Comment: @Alfe Exactly, that’s why `struct.calcsize('db')` is 9 (note that in C, it would usually be 12 as words need to be filled completely).

Comment: Yes, @poke, nice notion to swap the two elements to display that the padding does not belong to the byte but to the double.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`struct.pack` is usually used to access memory structures, not files. In memory, accessing data which occupies several bytes at an odd/unaligned address can cause exceptions or performance loss.

That's why compilers align the data (usually on a 4 or 8 byte boundary) and [the `struct` module](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/struct.html) in Python does the same.

To disable this, you can use the first character of the format string to set the byte order and alignment. In your case, try `struct.pack("=bi",1,1)`

If you don't specify anything, then an implicit `@` which means "native byte order, size and alignment". [See the documentation for other options](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/struct.html).

Answer (score 4):

[Yes, it is.](http://docs.python.org/3/library/struct#byte-order-size-and-alignment)

> By default, C types are represented in the machine’s native format and byte order, and properly aligned by skipping pad bytes if necessary (according to the rules used by the C compiler).

If you don't want alignment, just specify a byte order by starting your format string with `'='`, `'<'`, or `'>'` (same as `'!'`).

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](http://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html):

> By default, the result of packing a given C struct includes pad bytes in order to maintain proper alignment for the C types involved; similarly, alignment is taken into account when unpacking. This behavior is chosen so that the bytes of a packed struct correspond exactly to the layout in memory of the corresponding C struct.

`i` is a 4-byte integer which will be placed on its own *word*. As such, anything next to it, that doesn’t fill a word, will be padded to do that. You can override this behavior by specifying a [byte order](http://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) without native alignment.

That’s why—with more complex structs—the ordering of the things inside matters a lot.

See also the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

See [the documentation for struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html); in particular it says

> By default, the result of packing a given C struct includes pad bytes in order to maintain proper alignment for the C types involved; similarly, alignment is taken into account when unpacking. This behavior is chosen so that the bytes of a packed struct correspond exactly to the layout in memory of the corresponding C struct.

And see e.g. this Stack Overflow question for C struct memory layout: [C struct memory layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748995/c-struct-memory-layout)

In short, the integer is 4 bytes and therefore it must start at a multiple of 4. If you change the order of b and i around, the problem should't arise.