# How do I figure out the size of struct members and paddings?

Tags: c, struct, padding

Say if I have a struct as:

```
struct simple_struct_1
{
  long long a;
  char b;
  long c;
};
```

Address of a is: `0x7ffd415c8b20`
Address of b is: `0x7ffd415c8b28`
Address of c is: `0x7ffd415c8b30`
size of `simple_struct_1` is `24`

I have printed the address of each member and the size of the struct, how do I show how this struct is laid down in memory? Like if in the `simple_struct_1`, `a` occupies 111 bytes and has 222 padding bytes after which `b` occupies 333 bytes with 0 padding bytes after it, and `c` occupies 444 bytes with 555 bytes of padding after it.

Comment: This looks similar to [Struct memory layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748995/c-struct-memory-layout)

Comment: Also print the `sizeof()` of each member. It will give you their size in `char`. You can then easily deduce how many bytes a `char` is from the addresses.

Comment: In general using or relying on a specific memory layout of a struct is going to produce buggy code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `offsetof` and `sizeof` to get details on each individual field and the size of the structure as a whole, such as with:

```
printf ("a      is %d@%d\n", sizeof(simple_struct_1.a), offsetof(simple_struct_1, a));
printf ("b      is %d@%d\n", sizeof(simple_struct_1.b), offsetof(simple_struct_1, b));
printf ("c      is %d@%d\n", sizeof(simple_struct_1.c), offsetof(simple_struct_1, c));
printf ("struct is %d@0\n",  sizeof(simple_struct_1));
```

That should enable you to work out:

- the offsets and sizes of all fields;
- the gaps *between* the fields; and
- the gap after the last field (combine its offset and size with the size of the entire structure.

Don't worry about padding *before* the first field, the ISO standard forbids that.

For example, let's say you see the following output on the left, the sizes and gaps are shown on the right:

```
a      is 16@0        16 bytes for a long long
                      no gap (0 + 16 = 16, next at 16)
b      is 1@16         1 byte  for a char
                       7 bytes gap (16 + 1 = 17, next at 24)
c      is 8@24         8 bytes for a long
struct is 32@0        no gap at end (24 + 8 = 32, next at 32)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `offsetof()` macro to find the offset in bytes of each field from the first member (which must have the same address as the `struct` since no padding is allowed to precede the first member).

Combining this information with the sizes of the various members (and the size of the whole `struct` to find the number of trailing padding bytes), obtained using the `sizeof` operator, allows one to deduce where the padding bytes are. Here is a program that prints out member addresses and offsets. It also prints a graphic representation of member bytes and padding bytes; dashes indicate padding bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct simple_struct_1 {
    long long a;
    char b;
    long c;
};

char * graph_member(char *ptr, size_t member_sz, size_t padding_sz);

int main(void)
{
    struct simple_struct_1 my_struct;

    printf("sizeof (struct simple_struct_1) = %zu\n",
           sizeof (struct simple_struct_1));
    putchar('\n');

    void *ptra = &(my_struct.a);
    void *ptrb = &(my_struct.b);
    void *ptrc = &(my_struct.c);

    size_t offset_a = offsetof(struct simple_struct_1, a);
    size_t offset_b = offsetof(struct simple_struct_1, b);
    size_t offset_c = offsetof(struct simple_struct_1, c);

    /* Allocate memory for struct padding visualization */
    char *graph = malloc(sizeof my_struct + 1);

    if (graph == NULL) {
        perror("Virtual memory exhausted");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *ptr = graph;

    printf("&(my_struct.a) = %p\n", ptra);
    printf("sizeof my_struct.a = %zu\n", sizeof my_struct.a);
    putchar('\n');
    ptr = graph_member(ptr,
                       sizeof my_struct.a,
                       offset_b - sizeof my_struct.a);

    printf("&(my_struct.b) = %p\n", ptrb);
    printf("sizeof my_struct.b = %zu\n", sizeof my_struct.b);
    printf("&(my_struct.b) - &(my_struct.a) = %zu\n", offset_b - offset_a);
    putchar('\n');
    ptr = graph_member(ptr,
                       sizeof my_struct.b,
                       offset_c - offset_b - sizeof my_struct.b);

    printf("&(my_struct.c) = %p\n", ptrc);
    printf("sizeof my_struct.c = %zu\n", sizeof my_struct.c);
    printf("&(my_struct.c) - &(my_struct.b) = %zu\n", offset_c - offset_b);
    putchar('\n');
    ptr = graph_member(ptr,
                       sizeof my_struct.c,
                       sizeof my_struct - offset_c - sizeof my_struct.c);

    /* Null-terminate graph string and display */
    ptr = '\0';
    puts(graph);

    free(graph);

    return 0;
}

char * graph_member(char *ptr, size_t member_sz, size_t padding_sz)
{
    /* Indicate member */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < member_sz; i++) {
        *ptr = '*';
        ++ptr;
    }

    /* Indicate padding */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < padding_sz; i++) {
        *ptr = '-';
        ++ptr;
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

Sample program output:

```
sizeof (struct simple_struct_1) = 24

&(my_struct.a) = 0x7ffee4af4610
sizeof my_struct.a = 8

&(my_struct.b) = 0x7ffee4af4618
sizeof my_struct.b = 1
&(my_struct.b) - &(my_struct.a) = 8

&(my_struct.c) = 0x7ffee4af4620
sizeof my_struct.c = 8
&(my_struct.c) - &(my_struct.b) = 8

*********-------********
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `pahole` (poke -a -hole). This will help exactly how you need it.

Here is a reference to it. [pahole](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/pahole.1.html)