# Does a C struct hold its members in a contiguous block of memory?

Tags: c

Let's say my code is:

```
typedef stuct {
  int x;
  double y;
  char z;
} Foo;
```

would `x`, `y`, and `z`, be right next to each other in memory? Could pointer arithmetic 'iterate' over them? 
My C is rusty so I can not quite get the program right to test this.
Here is my code in full.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int x;
  double y;
  char z;
} Foo;


int main() {
  Foo *f = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
  f->x = 10;
  f->y = 30.0;
  f->z = 'c';
  // Pointer to iterate.
  for(int i = 0; i == sizeof(Foo); i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      printf(*(f + i));
    }
    else if (i == (sizeof(int) + 1)) {
      printf(*(f + i));
    }
    else if (i ==(sizeof(int) + sizeof(double) + 1)) {
      printf(*(f + i));
    }
    else {
      continue;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, you can't be sure since the compiler may pad fields in the structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Struct memory layout in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748995/struct-memory-layout-in-c)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it is not guaranteed for `struct` members to be contiguous in memory.

From §6.7.2.1 point 15 in the C standard (page 115 [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)):

> There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

Most of the times, something like:

```
struct mystruct {
    int a;
    char b;
    int c;
};
```

Is indeed aligned to `sizeof(int)`, like this:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11
[a         ][b][padding][c          ]
```

Comment: Diagram says it all. Nice!

Comment: I am guessing there is no way to determine the length of the padding? Also, why is there padding?

Comment: Also, great use of the byte layout.

Comment: @DavidFrick there is, with `alignof()`. The padding is there most of the times for performance reasons, it's faster to operate with slots the same size as the CPU registers even if the data is smaller.

Answer (score 13):

Yes and no.

Yes, the members of a struct are allocated within a contiguous block of memory. In your example, an object of type `Foo` occupies `sizeof (Foo)` contiguous bytes of memory, and all the members are within that sequence of bytes.

But no, there is no guarantee that the members themselves are adjacent to each other. There can be padding bytes between any two members, or after the last one. The standard does guarantee that the first defined member is at offset 0, and that all the members are allocated in the order in which they're defined (which means you can sometimes save space by reordering the members).

Normally compilers use just enough padding to satisfy the alignment requirements of the member types, but the standard doesn't require that.

So you can't (directly) iterate over the members of a structure. If you want to do that, and if all the members are of the same type, use an array.

You *can* use the [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) macro, defined in `<stddef.h>`, to determine the byte offset of (non-bitfield) member, and it can sometimes be useful to use that to build a data structure that can be used to iterate over the members of a structure. But it's tedious, and rarely more useful than simply referring to the members by name -- particularly if they have different types.

Comment: This answered  would have been my next question ie. is there a way to tell the padding then using pointer arithmetic with the padding in mind. Interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> would x, y, and z, be right next to each other in memory?

No. The struct memory allocation layout is implementation dependent - there is no guarantee struct members are right next to each other. One reason is memory padding, which is

> Could pointer arithmetic 'iterate' over them?

No. You can only do pointer arithmetic for pointers to the same type.

Comment: I don't think "the same type" is the issue here.  If you've got a struct with three `int`s in it, it isn't okay to use pointer-arithmetic to iterate from the first int to the last even though they are the same type because they are each separate objects.

Answer (score 1):

> would x, y, and z, be right next to each other in memory?

They *could* be, but don't have to be. The placement of elements in structures is not mandated by the ISO C standard.

In general, compiler will place the elements at some offset that is "optimal" for the architecture it compiles to. So, on 32-bit CPUs, most compilers will, by default, place elements at offsets that are multiples of 4 (as that will make for most efficient access). But, most compilers also have ways to specify different placement (alignment).

So, if you have something like:

```
struct X {
    uint8_t a;
    uint32_t b;
};
```

Then offset of `a` would be `0`, but offset of `b` would be `4` on most 32-bit compilers with default options.

> Could pointer arithmetic 'iterate' over them?

Not like the code in you example. Pointer arithmetic on pointers to structures is defined to add/subtract the address with the *size* of the structure. So, if you have:

```
struct X a[2];
struct X *p = a;
```

then `p+1 == a+1`.

To "iterate" over elements you would need to cast the `p` to `uint8_t*` and then add the offset of the element to it (using `offsetof` standard macro), element by element.

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see padding for the example struct you provided.  I would change `b` to be of type `uint32_t` or something like that which has stricter alignment requirements than `uint8_t`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons You are correct that `uint32_t` is a better example, updated. But, it is quite possible that even with `uint8_t` there would be padding, for faster access.

Comment: I wrote a quick program to test on my specific configuration and `sizeof(struct X)` came out to `2` when both members are `uint8_t`.  I'll have to consult the standard to see if there's anything about whether padding is allowed if alignment requirements can be met without padding.

Comment: IANALL, but I have used compilers that would pad in this scenario. Accessing odd addresses may be slower even if you access byte. This is not the case for the x86, but there are _many_ CPUs out there...

Comment: I just read the section in the C11 standard working draft on structs, and can confirm nothing in there preventing adding padding even if the type is already aligned. (section 6.7.2.1, if you're interested)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the padding decided on by the compiler (which is influenced by the requirements and advantages on the target architecture). The C standard does guarantee that there is to be no padding before the first member of a `struct`, but after that, you cannot assume anything. However, if the `sizeof` the `struct` does equal the `sizeof` each of its constituent types, then there is no padding.

You can enforce no padding with a compiler-specific directive. On MSVC, that's:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
// your struct...
#pragma pack(pop)
```

GCC has `__attribute__((packed))` for the equivalent effect.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with trying to use pointer arithmetic in this matter.

The first issue, as has been mentioned in other answers, is that there could be padding throughout the struct throwing off your calculations.

C11 working draft 6.7.2.1 p15: (**bold emphasis mine**)

> Within  a  structure  object,  the  non-bit-field  members  and  the  units  in  which  bit-fields
>   reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared.  A pointer to a
>   structure  object,  suitably  converted,  points  to  its  initial  member  (or  if  that  member  is  a
>   bit-field,  then  to  the  unit  in  which  it  resides),  and  vice  versa.   **There  may  be  unnamed
>   padding within a structure object**, but not at its beginning.

The second issue is that pointer arithmetic is done in multiples of the size of the type being pointed to.  In the case of a struct, if you add 1 to a pointer to a struct, the pointer will be pointing to an object after the struct.  Using your example struct `Foo`:

```
Foo x[3];
Foo *y = x+1; // y points to the second Foo (x[1]), not the second byte of x[0]
```

6.5.6 p8:

> When  an  expression  that  has  integer  type  is  added  to  or  subtracted  from  a  pointer,  the result has the type of the pointer operand.  If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original
>   array elements equals the integer expression.  In other words, if the expression **P** points to the *i*-th  element  of  an  array  object,  the  expressions **(P)+N** (equivalently, **N+(P)**)  and **(P)-N** (where **N** has the value *n*) point to, respectively, the *i*+*n*-th and *i*−*n*-th elements of the  array  object,  provided  they  exist.

A third issue is that performing pointer-arithmetic such that the result points more than one past the end of the object causes undefined behavior, as does dereferencing a pointer to one element past the end of the object obtained through the pointer arithmetic.  So even if you had a struct containing three `int`s with no padding inbetween and took a pointer to the first `int` and incremented it to point to the second int, dereferencing it would cause undefined behavior.

More from 6.5.6: (***bold-italic emphasis mine***)

> Moreover,  if  the  expression **P** points  to  the  last element of an array object, the expression **(P)+1** points one past the last element of the
>   array  object,  and  if  the  expression **Q** points  one  past  the  last  element  of  an  array  object, the  expression **(Q)-1** points  to  the  last  element  of  the  array  object.  If  both  the  pointer operand  and  the  result  point  to  elements  of  the  same  array  object,  or  one  past  the  last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.  ***If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.***

A fourth issue is that dereferencing a pointer to one type as another type results in undefined behavior.  This attempt at type-punning is often referred to as a strict-aliasing violation. The following is an example of undefined behavior through strict-aliasing violation even though the data types are the same size (assuming 4-byte int and float) and nicely aligned:

```
int x = 1;
float y = *(float *)&x;
```

6.5 p7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type
>     of the object,
> - a type  that  is  the  signed  or  unsigned  type  corresponding 
>     to  the  effective  type  of  the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a
>     qualified version of the effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate  or  union  type  that  includes  one  of  the 
>     aforementioned  types  among  its members (including, recursively, a
>     member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

Summary:
No, a C struct does not necessarily hold its members in contiguous memory, and even if it did, the pointer arithmetic you still couldn't do what you want to do with pointer arithemetic.